# Use a nested Resource or have a collection on the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have 2 Models, 'Device' and 'DeviceActivity' where Device has many Device Activities. Now if i would use regular resource nesting i would end up with something like

```
/devices/1/activities
```

or

```
/devices/1/activities/1
```

What i want is to access

```
/devices/activities
```

where i want to show all activities of all devices, like an activity stream. Is creating a collection on the Devices resource the right way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the solution

```
resources :devices do   
    collection do
      resources :activities, :controller => 'device_activities'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I have to wait "2 days" ;/

Comment: Didn't know this, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

so you want a GET /devices/activities so far as i read [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) this is not covered but you may define this in the routing yourself in the routes like

```
match "devices/activities" => 'devices#activities',    :as => :devices_activities
```

so you only need to implement the activities method in your DevicesController with the view respectively

Comment: Hi, thanks but i found the right solution by nesting a collection and then a resource inside that collection.